# How to put the value of a function inside the template literal?

Tags: javascript, html

Im making a comment system and is required to put the stars inside of template literal with the purpose that the number of stars stay next to the name of the person.
Until now the value is showing me "undefined"
screenshoot [screenshot comment system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtTsi.png)

this is the javascript code

```
const txtNombre = document.getElementById("text-nombre");
const txtParrafo = document.getElementById("text-area");
const boton = document.getElementById("btnAgregar");
const listado = document.getElementById("contenedor-filas");
const radio = document.getElementsByName("rate");

boton.addEventListener("click", agregarALista);

function agregarALista() {
    let nombre = txtNombre.value;
    var valor = txtParrafo.value;

    const elHtml = document.createElement("div");

    elHtml.innerHTML = `
    <div class="row" id="fila-segunda">
        <div class = "col-6">
            ${nombre}
        </div>

        <div class = "col-6">
            ${estrellitas()}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="fila-tercera">
        <div class = "col">
            ${valor}
        </div>
    </div>
    `;
    listado.appendChild(elHtml);

    txtNombre.value = "";
    txtParrafo.value = "";
}




let estrellitas = function() {
    radio.forEach(function(elementos) {
        if (elementos.checked) {
            estrellas = document.createElement("h3");
            estrellas.setAttribute("class", "stars");
            let s = "";
            for (i = 0; i < elementos.value; i++) {
                s += "★";
            }
            estrellas.textContent = s;
            listado.appendChild(estrellas);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `estrellitas()` is missing a return statement and will therefore return  `undefined`. Otherwise, your syntax for including function return values in string template literals is correct:

```js
let x = (a, b) => a > b;
let a = 10, b = 20;
console.log(`${a} is greater than ${b}? ${x(a, b)}`);
```